# difference between continue and quit in Emacs Lisp debugger

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

```
(progn
  (print 11)
  (/ 1 0)
  (print 22)
  (/ 2 0)
  (print 33))
```

When I press C-M-x on that expression, Emacs invokes debugger when it fails at (/ 1 0). When I press c for continue instead of q for quit, debugger still exits without executing (print 22) or (/ 2 0). The only difference here is that c exits with the message

```
progn: Arithmetic error
```

What is an example code where c and q make big difference and when should I type c rather than q?

Comment: Difference? There's really no *similarity* between "continue" and "quit". Either you're resuming execution, or you're aborting it. Whether the end results will be significantly different very much depends upon the *reason* that you are in the debugger to begin with, and possibly the type of error-handling currently in effect. In your example, continuing the execution very rapidly leads to execution ending with an error message, but that's still not the same thing as having manually aborted the execution from the debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference can be shown in any code that does not stop the execution, i.e. does not contain an error (for example, when called by `debug`).

Comment: Jisang Yoo: see also `C-u M-x apropos-variable RET debug-on- RET` and `C-u M-x apropos-command RET debug-on- RET`

Comment: n.b. For a contrived demonstration based on the code in the question: `(progn (print 11) (debug) (print 22) (debug) (print 33))`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is easiest to see when you use `debug-on-signal`.  With this setting, the debugger gets called when an error is signalled, even if that error is handled by an enclosing `condition-case`.  In such a situation `c` will continue the normal execution (i.e. signal the error, which in turn causes the handler code to be run, which may then continue execution normally).

Answer (score 0):

At first it seemed to me like a very obvious question,
but after trying to build an example, I actually had to look in the `info`.
So let me summarize what I've clarified for myself:

<kbd>c</kbd> in `edebug` is not the same as <kbd>c</kbd> in `gdb`.
This one just stops for one second at each breakpoint and eventually quits.
I don't see at the moment how it can be useful to anyone.
The equivalent is instead <kbd>g</kbd>: this one will continue until next breakpoint
and stop there.

Here's a code example:

```
(defun foo ()
  (setq x (loop for i from 1 to 100
             collecting (* i i)))
  (setq y (nth 5 x))
  (incf y))

(foo)
```

To `edebug` it:

1. Paste this code into `*scratch*`
2. Move point inside `foo` and <kbd>C-u C-M-x</kbd> (calls `edebug-defun`)
3. Move point to `y` in `setq y` and <kbd>M-x edebug-set-breakpoint</kbd>
4. Move point to the closing paren in `(foo)` and <kbd>C-j</kbd>
5. You're now in `edebug`. Here you could do step 3 with the shortcut <kbd>b</kbd> 
   instead of <kbd>M-x ...</kbd>
6. You'll find that proceeding with <kbd>SPC</kbd> is tedious, since it will
   move though each statement of the loop each time.
7. But if you press <kbd>g</kbd> you'll skip past the whole loop, ending up
   in the statement that you're supposedly interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Another difference is with respect to recursive edit. For example, I could invoke query-replace and then enter recursive edit and then type `(/ 1 0)` and evaluate it to enter debugger. Now if I press q, we are back to top level and no longer running query-replace. But if I press c instead, I am still inside recursive edit.

**Update** another difference. While in debugger, `c` is bound to `debugger-continue` which is a wrapper around `exit-recursive-edit`
and `q` is bound to `top-level`. That means any difference known about `exit-recursive-edit` vs `top-level` applies. See [Recursive Edit - Emacs Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Recursive-Edit.html) for difference.

Here's an example adapted from an example in [Recursive Editing - Emacs Lisp  Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Recursive-Editing.html) to test differences.

```
(defun simple-rec ()
  (forward-word 1)
  (message "111")
  (debug)
  (message "222")
  (forward-word 1))
```